# android Google Places API getCurrentPlace on background

Tags: android, google-maps

This sample code is taken from the official site :

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
```

The `getCurrentPlace`'s first parameter is an object of `GoogleApiClient` which i initialized in my `Activity`.

And then (also in the `Activity`) theres a `callback` :

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
      Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
          placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
          placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
    }
    likelyPlaces.release();
  }
});
```

Is it possible to call `getCurrentPlace` and listening to `setResultCallback` on the background? (`Service/IntentService/BroadcastReceiver`)

Could someone give me a clue how to do it?

I got stuck because i cant pass `mGoogleApiClient` (not `Parcelable`) to `BroadcastReceiver`

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully implemented it starting from the previous work taken from this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28535885/1361250

```
public class PlacesService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "GPS";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

        if (mLastLocation == null || location.distanceTo(mLastLocation) > 500) // Request nearby places if you moved 500 meters further
            MyActivity.getInstance().requestPlaces(); // Call your activity (assuming it's a singleton, modify it to your own case)

        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null)
    {
        // Check permission
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++)
        {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
}
```

In your activity you first have to start your service:

```
startService(new Intent(context, PlacesService.class));
```

And implement the method called from the Service:

```
void requestPlaces()
{
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces)
        {
            List<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces)
            {
                places.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace()); // Store places for your own use
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
}
```